# Fubini without CH

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, measure-theory, integration

In *Real and Complex Analysis*, Rudin gives an example (due to Sierpinski) of a function $f:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ separately Lebesgue-measurable in each argument, such that
$$ 
\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1f(x,y)\,dy
\neq
\int_0^1 dy\int_0^1f(x,y)\,dx
$$
(all integrals are w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$). The construction of $f$ requires the Continuum Hypothesis, and my question is: What happens if we negate CH? Does it then follow that all functions $f:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ separately Lebesgue-measurable in each argument satisfy the conclusion of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: [This paper by Friedman](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256047607) appears to show that a slightly weaker statement is consistent with ZFC: if both iterated integrals make sense then they are equal.

Comment: Does this thing have anything to do with this?: http://jdh.hamkins.org/freilings-axiom-of-symmetry-graduate-student-colloquium-april-2016/

Comment: Martins axiom (consistent with not-CH) will be enough to do Sierpinski's example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [Cardinal Conditions for Strong Fubini Theorems](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2001569?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents),
Joseph Shipman
Transactions of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 321, No. 2 (Oct., 1990), pp. 465-481.

[image]

In general: Let $(X,A,μ)$ and $(Y,B,ν)$ be $σ$-finite measure spaces. The strong Fubini axiom ($SFA^∗$) asserts that whenever the iterated integrals for some $f:X×Y→[0,∞)$ are defined then they must be equal. It is known that for $X=Y=R$ and $μ=ν=$ Lebesgue measure, $CH$ implies not-$SFA^∗$ and the above paper shows that non(Lebesgue null)$<$Cov(Lebesgue null) implies $SFA^∗$.

You may also look at [Strong Fubini axioms from measure extension axioms](http://emis.ams.org/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc9202/zakr.pdf) for extensions